# How to solve com.library.android error?

Tags: android, tesseract, tess-two

```
apply plugin: 'com.library.android'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    }
}
```

The android studio says plugin with id `com.library.android` is not found. I also downloaded android support repository plugin. This was the gradle file for tess two folder. How do I solve?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is that you're putting `apply plugin: 'com.library.android'` in the wrong gradle file.

There are two gradle files(if your project has only one module). One is app level `build.gradle`, while the other is project level `build.gradle`.  Same names - so, confusing. You are using it in the project level build.gradle where you cannot keep such plugins.

Cut `apply plugin: 'com.library.android'` from your current gradle and paste it in the app level build.gradle.